# Parse String to Organize By Row with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

This is probably something easy to accomplish.  I have some dates in my MySQL database, (and I am using PHP).  Some are stored as such `2010-08-25 11:00:00`, while others are stored as `2010-08-25T08:00:00`

My question is: I am selecting the dates from the database, and then using `ORDER BY start_date`

However, I have noticed that when the date string includes a "T", it is pushing it down in the order.  For example, my dates being returned are:

```
 2010-08-25 11:00:00
 2010-08-25 14:15:00
 2010-08-25T08:00:00
 2010-08-25T14:30:00
 2010-08-25T15:00:00
```

As you can see, events at 8am are showing up after events at 2:15pm.

Any ideas on how I can re-arrange it so that the 8am events are moved toward the top?

Thanks.

Comment: fix your data. it's not a good idea to mix date formats. use mysql datetime consistently.

Comment: `while others are stored as 2010-08-25T08:00:00` That is your fault. You should convert these values to datetime format.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am just taking over the database.  Any ideas on how to convert all the entries?  Also, which is more preferable? With or without the "T"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just get the list of dates into PHP, use string functions to convert the 'T' to a space, and then sort the list.

Definitely not a good solution though. It would be better to fix the data in your database, if possible.